# How can I easily defeat Plantera?

Tags: terraria

Ever since I defeated the all the bosses (except Plantera) I've been wondering - How do I defeat Plantera? I tried fighting her once, but failed once she reached stage two. I found her bulb again, but before battling her I want to prepare myself properly.

What armor should I use? Weapons? Accessories?  Anything else in particular that will help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there are a number of strategies you can employ to beat Plantera, but the following one has served me well.

### The Gear

Since you've beaten the three mechanical bosses (a requirement as of 1.2.3 to get Plantera to spawn), you should have several [Hallowed Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Bar). Use them to make the [Hallowed Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Armor) if you don't already have it. If you're adventurous, plunder the underground Jungle and mine for [Chlorophyte Ore](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Ore) to make the [Chlorophyte armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_armor). It takes a lot of Chlorophyte ore to make the full armor set, but it's worth it in my opinion. Note that you'll need the appropriate pickaxe or drill to mine Chlorophyte (both of which are crafted with hallowed bars). Farming a mechanical boss or two again may be necessary to get enough bars (the Destroyer is my favorite one to farm).

If you do plunder the underground dungeon, keep on the lookout for [Life Fruit](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Life_Fruit). The permanent boost to your health that each one provides is always a good thing!

As far as weaponry goes, I like using the [Megashark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Megashark) with [crystal bullets](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Bullet). A full hallowed armor set with the hallowed helmet yields a full-set bonus granting a 25% chance to not consume ammo. This is great when coupled with the Megashark! The Chlorophyte helmet has a similar bonus (though only a 20% chance not to consume ammo).

Accessories are up to you, but I like rolling with the following:

- [Charm of Myths](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Charm_of_Myths): absolutely necessary as it gives life regen and a 15-second cooldown on health potions
- [Cross Necklace](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cross_Necklace): increases your length of invincibility after being hit (which means you get hit less!)
- [Leaf Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Leaf_Wings): These cost a fortune (1 platinum coin), but wings of any type are much better than the rocket boots / balloon
- [Obsidian Shield](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian_Shield): Prevents knockback and +2 defense
- [Spectre Boots](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Spectre_Boots): Gives me the ability to run fast (wings override the rocket boot portion of this accessory, so Hermes boots will be just as fine)

I don't pay much attention to the stats on my accessories, but having some additional defense on a few of them never hurts.

Make sure you have plenty of potions:

- Greater healing potions are ideal
- Iron skin potions
- Thorns potions
- Swiftness potions
- Hunter potions (a nice to have ... not necessary)
- Regeneration potions are very helpful
- Bowls of soup (and other similar items) are also useful

### The Environment

I like mining out an "arena" in the jungle where I can do battle. I essentially make a large square that I can fly around in (this is where the wings come in handy), walling in passages as necessary to prevent other enemies from wandering in (or, more importantly, me from stumbling into those passages by accident during the heat of battle). You'll need a few things for your arena:

- A campfire is essential (I usually place mine at the bottom of the arena)
- A couple of [heart lanterns](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Lantern) (in opposite corners of the square) are essential
- A small pool of honey can be useful
- A [heart statue](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Statue) (or two), wired up to 1-second timers are very useful
- Spawn the nurse into a protected, yet easy to reach area for instant healing.

### The Fight

Once you've got the arena built, make sure you know how to get from the bulb to the arena (if your arena isn't located immediately near the bulb), and lure Plantera there once you've broken the bulb. As you lure it to your arena, you may have to move slow enough to prevent Plantera from de-spawning (I seem to have had that problem in the past). Once you're in the arena, it simply becomes a matter of flying around the arena, kiting Plantera as you unload your Megashark. Phase one should be relatively easy; just avoid Plantera as you fly and shoot. Phase two becomes a little harder, and switching to a strong melee weapon may be necessary from time to time to keep the smaller tendrils from swarming you. Regardless, keep kiting, keep quaffing health potions, and keep picking up hearts from the heart statue to stay alive. I assure you that Plantera can be solo'ed ... if I can do it, anyone can. :-)
Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the Megashark, though I use Chlorophyte Bullets so I don't have to worry so much about aim.

Comment: Chlorophyte bullets are certainly an option, but I personally like the crystal bullets because you get some splash damage for the ones that hit, and they're *way* easier to craft (crystal shards are super easy to find in underground Hallow). Either way, the Megashark is what's important due to its 50% chance to not consume ammo. Super useful stat!

Comment: I already have the Megashark,Hallowed Greaves,and Hallowed Chestplate,but ya,working on the helmet.

Comment: I won. Ya,hooray. I did exactly what you said and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! It's a great feeling to finally beat a boss like Plantera. Now on to the jungle dungeon to fight the Golem...

Comment: @Jonah Bishop - You go to the Lizhard to fight Golem. BTW,Golem,in my opinion,is a really easy boss.

Comment: *Lihzard Temple

Comment: I personaly think that ichor bullets work just as good as crystal or chloryphite.

Comment: As for the use of heart statues, I recommend multiple wiring around the statue using the 3 different wrenches with 2 pressures plates disposed 1 block next to the statue, so you can spawn hearts MUCH more frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're playing by yourself, then yes, follow what they have been saying. But as a duo player with my friend, I have made myself a full set of turtle armor. It took me about 3 hours of gameplay to get all the chlorophyte, however... but then I used spelunker potions. :P Have your friend use a ranger set, mainly megashark with crystal bullets or, if possible, chlorophyte. I have 73 defense with the armor and accessories, and that reduces damage by a huge amount.

Answer (score 0):

Im still working on Plantera aswell but yes,Get A Turtle set (Its worth the trouble to find Chrolyphyte) And build a rectangle arena As big as you want then from the sides of the area and Put Down wood platforms and then circle Plantera im Trying it with a friend or 2 with weapons Being Me:Terra Blade Friends:Gungnir and Cholophyte Claymore/Horsemans Blade.Also Try setting up a House with a bed and set your spawn point that way if someone dies they respawn back and Plantera doesnt Despawn and if your friend dies just run until they come back We have done that but with weak weapons and got Plantera down Really Low.I Hope This Helped You

Answer (score 0):

For armor, use at least hallowed or frost (if you can) then get a strong meelee weapon like beam sword, true sword nights edge, Excalibur or terra blade if possible.

Dig out a 50 by 50 arena to dodge and then place wooden platforms. For magic weapons use crystal storm for the less mana consumption or cursed flame for the bouncing.

Use a werewolf to kill the tentacles.

You might want to use a flame thrower or sharanga for fire damage.
Use wings for flying around. Also, you should use several campfires around the arena and heart lanterns below said campfires, and a pool of honey and charm of myths, all for a massive regen boost. Also heart statues with one second timers for 20 health per heart collected.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the arena-approach the two highest rated comments suggest, I generally go for a teleporter tunnel approach.

Create a long tunnel (on PC, I suggest around 2 screen widths, that's around 70-100 blocks) and I suggest a height of 6 to 7 blocks just for ease of aim (Plantera doesn't move in a straight line). Place teleporting platforms on each end, wire them together with switches on each end. Create a wall with an opening to shoot into the tunnel while you're standing on the platforms on each end.

The idea is to lure and keep Plantera in the tunnel while you shoot at it from the little openings, teleporting to the other end of the tunnel when Plantera gets too close. The tunnel length should be such that Plantera won't despawn as you jump from one end to the other.

This horizontal tunnel approach I found to be a bit easier than the arena, for one reason: I'm not that proficient with my movement on the grappling hooks. If you're careful, you can avoid almost all the attacks of Plantera this way. The Bouncing thorn ball won't go through the walls at the ends of the tunnel, nor will the seeds in first stage of fight.

Another option that requires a bit more focus, is a vertical tunnel. A tunnel 4-5 blocks wide, going straight down. Keeping yourself afloat with wings and grappling, you can use **Nimbus Rod** or **Crimson Rod** to create constant damaging effects to pair with Megashark. If you wish to try a vertical tunnel, it's best if you can fight the second stage while going down to automatically avoid the spores, but even on the largest maps the Plantera fight will take so long that you will run out of space on a single tunnel and will have to change direction.

Other than the different style "arena", equipment and helping items are identical to the post you chose.

Answer (score -1):

Use vampire knifes on them
You only need to kill the destroyer and then wait for solar eclipse you kill planterra in seconds. This might not always work very well in a small space so make sure if you are doing this do it in a BIG arena.

Comment: You didn't explained *anything*. Besides, VK can't be always obtainiable, because of worlds with corruption.

Comment: Vampire knives are not available until after Plantera has been defeated for the first time, so this answer is not viable for players on their first play-through.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's best to use magical harp, golden shower, greater mana potion and greater healing. You can weaken its defense, restore your mana and then use magical harp. Chlorophyte armour definitely helps as its set bonus is a crystal leaf that shoots enemies automatically, and it's good to use either the chlorophyte warhammer, which does 107 damage, or the chlorophyte sword, which is the best pre-Planterra sword. The cursed flames spellbook is also good, because the On Fire and Cursed Flame effects are highly effective.

Also, it becomes enraged whenever it exits its biome, which is bad cause it becomes faster and tries to tackle you. Make a spawn point in the underground jungle and then fight it in a arena and dodge its seeds and spiky balls.

With all this I killed Plantera in under two minutes.