# What armor to use for Golem with Magic Weapons?

Tags: terraria

I have just defeated Plantera but I have no idea what kind of armor I should wear to fight the Golem.

What is the best magic armor I can be wearing at this point in the game?

Comment: If you beat Plantera, Golem should be a pushover. He's much easier than Plantera.

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion based. Asking "what kind of gear should I use" is a [an answerable question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157756/how-can-i-easily-defeat-plantera), regarding boss fights. Perhaps this could be worded, better?

Answer (score 1):

> It's advised to arrive in updated sets for your preferred specialization: Shroomite armor for ranged characters, Turtle armor for melee characters, Spectre Armor for magic characters, or Beetle Armor for melee characters who have defeated Golem already. If you are a magic character who has not attempted the Hardmode Dungeon yet, they should use Chlorophyte Armor. At minimum one would want Chlorophyte armor, Hallowed Armor,Mobile only.Dragon Armor or Frost Armor. Regardless of specialization one may prefer to use Beetle armor for the fight due to its high mitigation which is extremely useful for the Golem fight assuming you do not utilize the wall trick. NOTE:You need to have already defeated Golem to get Beetle armor.

As the wiki states, you should probably get spectre armor as you are a magic character. If you are low on ectoplasm you can use cholorophyte armor or beetle for overall survivability.

Comment: I'd suggest to highlight the armor names and space a little to make this block of text more appealing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the chlorophyte armor and a very good megashark with high velocity bullets when fighting the golem if you have not fought plantera first ,if you have then get the special material you can bye from the cyborg to make a new type of bullets. stock up on them and if you get three turtle shells then you should make turtle shell armor with a knockback shield. it will take some time to get the supplies necessary to make these items but it will be well worth the time taken in doing so. also some additional information on magic weapons, get the angry nimbus rod that is very rarely dropped by the angry nimbus cloud that spawns when it rains.

Comment: my apologies, I meant to say *buy*

Comment: You can edit your answer with the correction, take a look at the [Tour Page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are unclear how.