# How do you beat Plantera in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

So I looked at different videos on how do defeat Plantera but whenever I try to, I always die. All of the videos I watched included teleporters and some sort of gun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily defeat Plantera?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157756/how-can-i-easily-defeat-plantera)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plantera is basically a big arena test, all you need is a big enough arena, and you shouldn't have a problem. I usually keep my arena at ~200x200 blocks, but you can change it based on your comfort level with her.

For all classes except summoner, chlorophyte armor is good, although melee also can make use of turtle armor, and summoner should go for spider armor.

As for weapons, I usually got for Terra blade or life discs - melee, Daedalus stormbow - ranged with ichor and holy arrows, golden shower, life drain, and crystal serpent - magic, and for summoner - spider and optic staff. Use really whatever accessories suits your play style, but I'd recommend having at least leaf wings with the classes' respective emblems.

I'd also recommend having both the universal buffs, as well as class specific buffs for any fight as well. As for the actual strategy for beating plantera, fly around her in a circle to avoid her projectiles, while also keeping as much damage on her as possible, as for her second phase, same thing, but faster and avoiding her tentacles.